# Displaying a CAST datetime in RFC822 Format

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, rfc822

I would like to display a `CAST` datetime in an SQL table using the RFC822 format (ex:`Fri, 19 Nov 2010 13:43:39`) from the following `SELECT` (part of a larger statement found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217866/appending-text-to-for-xml-sql-select-statement))

```
*_snip_*

,(Select Cast(Cast(FieldValue as nvarchar(max)) as DateTime) 
  from dbo.UserDefinedData where UserDefinedFieldId = 298 
  and UserDefinedRowId = item.UserDefinedRowId) as [pubDate]
```

The bit of SQL below will retrieve the current date in the desired format.

How can I integrate it into the above statement (or is there a better way to achieve my goal)?

```
select left(datename(dw,getdate()),3)+', '+convert(varchar(20),getdate(),113)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
,(Select left(datename(dw,cast(fieldvalue as nvarchar(50))),3)+', '+
     convert(varchar(20),cast(fieldvalue as nvarchar(50)),113)
  from dbo.UserDefinedData where UserDefinedFieldId = 298  
  and UserDefinedRowId = item.UserDefinedRowId) as [pubDate]
```

Comment: [FieldValue] is ntext and I receive an "Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with datetime" error.  

(I would have mentioned it was ntext beforehand, but I'm not familiar with datatype relationships. It is from a DotNetNuke core module table that I would like to avoid changing datatypes on if possible).

Comment: The query executes sucessfully, but it is changing only some of the dates for some reason. ("2010-04-03 00:00:00.000" becomes "Sat, 4/3/2010" while "2010-04-10 00:00:00.000" becomes "Sat, 2010-04-10T00:00:00")

Comment: "2010-04-03 00:00:00.000" becomes "Sat, 2010-04-03 00:00:00.", and "2010-04-10 00:00:00.000" becomes "Sat, 2010-04-10 00:00:00.". This is SQL Server, correct? Are you sure there isn't something else in the values?

Comment: SQL Server, yes. I'm looking at the table at those are the complete values. The fact that the output doesn't look like 113 is strange, also.

Thanks for working on this.

Comment: Run this: declare @fieldvalue varchar(500) set @fieldvalue='2010-04-10 00:00:00.000' Select left(datename(dw,cast(@fieldvalue as nvarchar(50))),3)+', '+ convert(varchar(20),cast(@fieldvalue as nvarchar(50)),113)

Comment: Running that query gives me "Sat, 2010-04-10 00:00:00."

Comment: Any thoughts regarding the inconsistancy ("2010-04-03 00:00:00.000" becomes "Sat, 4/3/2010" while "2010-04-10 00:00:00.000" becomes "Sat, 2010-04-10T00:00:00"), or why date format 113 (
Fri, 19 Nov 2010 13:43:39) doesn't result?